# Does Node.js need a configuration setting to allow local filesystem reads?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js.  I am trying to read a file in an `async` function.  In the function I instantiate a class from a module I have created.  The constructor of that module calls a method tries to open and read an ASCII text file that is local to the module.  The problem is that when I try to do the read, Node just seems to skip over it.  No exceptions are thrown that I can see.  I am running this in a PyCharm debug session and can set breakpoints that are never triggered.

I have an absolute path to an existing file.  I have tried using `fs.readFile()` and `fs.createReadStream()` with the same result.

The `readFile` code I tried came from the Node docs [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs/)

```
fs.readFile(
    pathToFile, 'ascii', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err)
        }

        this.#file_contents = data
    }
);
```

The `createReadStream` docs suggested something like:

```
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

readableStream.on('error', function (error) {
    throw error
})

readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    this.#file_contents = chunk
})
```

Does Node need some configuration switch set to allow filesystem reads?

**Edit**

Thanks all, just what I needed!

Comment: No configuration is needed.  The read is just non-blocking and asynchronous.  That means calling `fs.readFile()` just initiates the reading and immediately returns and continues to execute the rest of your code.  Sometime later, it will call the callback with the file data.  This is how asynchronous operations work in nodejs.  There are synchronous operations if you want like `fs.readFileSync()` (though they shouldn't be used in a server except in startup code because they block the event loop).

Comment: If you put a `console.log(data)` in your callback, you will see it gets executed, but later after your other code has executed.  Note, you will generally NOT want to do asynchronous operations in a constructor function because you have no good way of communicating back either errors or completion.

Comment: Just as jfriend00 sayed. To test it, you can use the synchron functions of the fs module. They throw errors and block the event loop. Perhaps its easier for you to understand how sync/async functions in node work.

Comment: Streams `.creatReadStream` used to do `.pipe` to some other stream or to handle events and write Your own way of processing. `.readFile` simplifies it and returns `Buffer` - so if You expect text content do `data.toString()`. P.S. User VSCode it has inbuilt debug mode with ease.

Comment: No, you don't need any special configuation for node. But you probably should read a few tutorials about asynchronous programming in javascript ...

Answer (score 0):

No configuration is needed. The read is just non-blocking and asynchronous. That means calling `fs.readFile()` just initiates the reading and immediately returns and continues to execute the rest of your code.

Sometime later, it will call your callback with the file data. This is how asynchronous operations work in nodejs. There are synchronous operations if you want like `fs.readFileSync()` - though they shouldn't be used in a server except in startup code because they block the event loop and wreck the scalability of your server.

In fact, if you just do this in your file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const pathToFile = "./index.txt";

console.log("1");
fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf8', data => {
    console.log("2");
});
console.log("3");
```

You will see in your console:

```
1
3
2
```

This shows how `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  It will initiate its operation and then immediately return, letting more of your code execute before it completes and then eventually calls its callback.

---

If this was a single user script or if this was server initialization code, you could just do this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const pathToFile = "./index.txt";

console.log("1");
const data = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile, 'utf8');
console.log("2");
```

You will see in your console:

```
1
2
```